# Using Named Credentials and Auth Provider to manage security token for APEX Callout to an OAuth 2.0 REST API

Tags: oauth2, namedcredentials

I'm trying to do an [APEX Callout](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts#HTTP_.28RESTful.29_Services) to a OAuth 2.0 secured REST API

This is the API
https://developers.pandadoc.com/v1/reference#authentication-process

I want to use something to manage the security token rather than write APEX code to do it. And according to [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_about.htm&type=0) that's what Named Credentials are for. Specifically this passage:

> Salesforce manages all authentication for callouts that specify a
>   named credential as the callout endpoint so that you don’t have to.
>   You can also skip remote site settings, which are otherwise required
>   for callouts to external sites, for the site defined in the named
>   credential.

The problem I have is I'm trying to use an Auth Provider but there's no OAuth 2.0 option so I'm using OpenID.  Which if I understand correctly rides on OAuth 2.0. I'm not sure what the "Redirect URI" should be from the PandaDoc API side. I'm using the "Callback URL" but it's not working.

I have the whole flow working in Postman from the [Collection](https://developers.pandadoc.com/v1/reference#postman-collection) PandaDoc publishes. They also have a [video](https://youtu.be/vaL866FH7VY) showing the Postman setup.  I'm able to use the builtin Postman OAuth 2.0 Authorization to get the Access Token and make successful calls to the PandaDoc API.

In my case I'm calling PandaDoc API but this would be useful for anyone calling out from Salesforce to any OAuth 2.0 secured API.  I didn't find any good examples of how to make an Apex Callout to an OAuth 2.0 REST API.

Comment: I can think of two things right-away. Are you setting the correct content-type?
Also, what do you see in the Panda-Doc console for redirect uri?

Comment: Neither the "Named Credential" or "Auth. Provider" have a setting for content type. 
I get the error when I'm trying to save the Named Credential for PandaDoc because I have the box checked to "Start Authentication Flow on Save" 
The error I get from PandaDoc is:
"The requested redirect didn't match the client settings."
I'm not sure where to look in PandaDoc for a console.

Comment: Perhaps you would be better served at [Panda Doc](https://developers.pandadoc.com/discuss)  Edit: I see you've already posted this.

Comment: Already trying that too, but honestly it's more of a Salesforce question because the API works through Postman.
What I need to know is how to do the same thing in Salesforce.

Comment: If you want to do, what you did in POSTMAN, you can do this without using the NamedCredential feature. The same request can be sent over from salesforce, but I am guessing that is not what you're looking for.

Comment: I know I can hardcode the flow but what I'm looking for infrastructure to manage the connection and tokens as is described in the section in the documentation I highlighted.  Is hard coding what others are doing? It seems there should be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Named credential does have oAuth 2.0, the problem is with the Auth Provider. (I believe)

- Select Identity Type as "Named Principle"
- Then Select oAuth 2.0 as the Protocol

You will need to set up the AuthProvider as well and if they do not support OpenID Connect then you will need to create a custom auth provider according to the [HELP](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_plugin_custom.htm) document. I do not think it is a trivial exercise

The steps to do so are pretty detailed but one of the items in the registration class that is relevant to your question is quoted below

> Existing User Linking URL—Use to link existing Salesforce users to a third-party account. The user opens this URL in a browser, signs in to the third party, signs in to Salesforce, and approves the link

Someone please correct me if I am wrong in that since the desire here is to get a token for the external system a custom provider may need to be implemented.

Comment: I don't understand the need to "create a custom provider" my auth provider is the webservice I'm calling FROM Salesforce.  The way I'm understanding the Auth Provider is I should be able to configure that to be in this case Panda Doc.  Why doesn't Salesforce have a oAuth 2.0 provider in the list of options? It has Google, Facebook, Twitter and GitHub.

Comment: @HungryPipo - Was struggling with that myself but I think that in order to setup the oAuth flow to the external system a "Provider" needs to be configured. I'll admit I am not 100% on the terminology and reasons why just that it would seem to be the only way to do it. I would assume since SF maintains the credentials it needs all the configuration to be able to automatically request, access, and update the tokens. May be easier to just store the tokens in a private custom setting

Comment: @HungryPipo - If you want to see what the process looks like set up a named credential and provider to another SF instance. Then you may get an Idea of why you need to setup PandaDoc as a provider. If PandaDoc supported OpenID Connect then you would not need to do all that

Comment: Is that what others(SF orgs) do? How are external oAuth 2.0 services consumed from Salesforce? I would think Salesforce would want to make it easy to do?

Comment: @HungryPipo - I could not find any example where others have used named credentials and oAuth with anything but Salesforce or the listed providers. Typically they used username and password for those. It also struck me that all the documentation about named credentials and auth providers all seem to focus on access TO the SF instance.

Comment: Maybe @sfdcfox has some insight. I am interested on the direction for this as well. Sorry sfdcfox for at mentioning you directly but trying to pick your brain here.